# What is the lexical environment inside a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, this, arrow-functions, lexical-scope

I keep hearing that arrow functions inherit the value of `this` from their *Lexical Environment*.

Consider this example:

```js
let para = document.getElementById("para");
let article = document.getElementById("article");

article.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("I’m a <span> tag!", this);
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
para.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("I’m a <p> tag!", this));
```

```html
<p id="para">
  <span id="article">Click Me!</span>
</p>
```

Why is the value of `this` inside the arrow callback functions `undefined` (or in non-strict mode: `window`)? If the callback function is using the value of `this` from its lexical environment, shouldn’t the lexical environment be `addEventListener`?

Comment: I'd just think of it as this: whatever the value of `this` was when you created the function, that's also what it will be when the function runs. When you created the function, `this` was window. The fact that you then pass the function into addEventListener doesn't change anything.

Comment: And note that it really should be `undefined`, because you should be using strict mode everywhere anyway. In non-strict mode, it wouldn’t be `Window`, either, but `window`, which is the same as `globalThis`.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you, especially Sebastian. That line about evaluating arguments then calling the function clicked with me.

Comment: Could you please write this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function as `func(a, b)`, then first, `a` is evaluated, then `b` is evaluated, *then* `func` is called with the values of `a` and `b`.
`a` and `b` are not “inside” `func`.

It doesn’t matter which of the following code snippets you use — these are equivalent:

```js
const a = () => console.log(this);

addEventListener("click", a);
```

```js
addEventListener("click", () => console.log(this));
```

`addEventListener` *does* attempt to call its second argument with `this` set to the event’s `currentTarget`, but as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and various other [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/4642212), arrow functions *cannot be rebound*:

```js
"use strict";

(() => console.log(this)).call({ "my": "object" }); // Logs `undefined`.
```

I’m not quite sure what you mean by *“shouldn’t the lexical enironment be `addEventListener`?”*.
The lexical scope of an arrow function is the one it’s created in.
As an [arrow function is created](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiatearrowfunctionexpression), its scope and a special “lexical-this” flag are used to create a function object.
And when [called](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist), note that the attempt to perform the OrdinaryCallBindThis abstract operation, which normally sets `this`, does nothing for arrow functions.
Instead, the function body is executed as-is, in its original context.

Looking at your original code again, note that every single `this` is part of the same lexical environment — in fact, `this` is the same, in this code, no matter where you put it.
Note, in particular, that function arguments don’t create a new lexical environment.

```js
"use strict";

this; // `undefined`.

let para = document.getElementById("para", this); // Ignored argument, but is `undefined`.
let article = document.getElementById("article");

article.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(this); // Logs `undefined`.
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
para.addEventListener("click", (this, () => console.log(this))); // Logs `undefined`. Preceded by comma operator with discarded value `this`, but would be `undefined`.
```

In contrast, a `function` function would create a new lexical environment and would also be able to be rebound:

```js
article.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(this); // Logs `article`.
});
```

See [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/4642212) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the [Arrow Function on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description) they fully explained what the arrow function is and compared the traditional function to the arrow function.

According to MDN:

> Arrow function does not have its own bindings to this or super, and should not be used as methods.

Therefore, in your case, the arrow function is not gonna redefined `this` that means `this` is `window` object

And the traditional function is redefined `this` from what a function is called.

```js
para.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log(this);  // print p node elemnt
});
```